# Custom DropDownList filter for Kendo Grid not working properly

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui, asp.net-mvc-5, grid

I made a KENDO grid for our timesheets, and there's a column "Status". I made a custom dropdown filter that filters on contractstatus [PendingValidation, ConsultantApproved, ApproverApproved, AccountApproved]. Values for these statuses are 0,1,2 and 3. I want a DropDown that shows full status names, but filters on value.

Everything is going good, text is displayed by the use of resources, except nothing happens after clicking 'Filter'.

Before I made the custom dropdown, a numericTextBox was used showing "1, 2, 3 and 4" instead of the full status names. Filtering worked flawless then.

This JQuery I wrote to customize:

```
///Adjust the status column filter
    ///So that there is a dropdown with string values
    var grid = $("#grid").data("kendoGrid");
    //alter the filter of the status column
    grid.bind("filterMenuInit", function (e) {
          // If the filter is for the "Status" column...
        if (e.field == "Status") {
            e.container.find("div.k-filter-help-text").text("Filter op status:");
            e.container.find("span.k-dropdown:first").css("display", "none");
            e.container.find("span.k-dropdown:eq(1)").css("display","none");
            e.container.find("span.k-dropdown:eq(2)").css("display", "none");
            e.container.find("span.k-numerictextbox").css("display", "none");
            // Change the text field to a dropdownlist in the status filter menu.
            var dropDownList = e.container.find(".k-numeric-wrap:first");
                    dropDownList.removeClass("k-numeric-wrap")
                        .kendoDropDownList({
                         autoWidth: true,
                      dataTextField: "title",
                      dataValueField: "value",
                      dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                          data: [                             //TO-DO filter not working on id value
                              { title: "@Resources.PendingValidation", value: 0},
                              { title: "@Resources.ConsultantApproved", value: 1 },
                              { title: "@Resources.ApproverApproved", value: 2 },
                              { title: "@Resources.AccountApproved", value: 3 }
                          ]
                      }),
                      dataTextField: "title",
                      dataValueField: "value",
                      optionLabel: "--Kies een status--"
                })
          }
    });
    //end statusfilter
```

This is the grid:

```
 @(Html.Kendo().Grid<DownloadTimesheetsGridViewModel>()
    .Name("grid")
    .ToolBar(t =>
    {
        t.Template(Html.KendoGridToolbar(true, true).ToHtmlString());
    })
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.Year).Title(Resources.Year).ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("#= value #");
        columns.Bound(c => c.Date).Title(Resources.Month).Format("{0:MMMM}").ClientGroupHeaderTemplate("Month : #=  kendo.toString(value, 'MMMM') #").Filterable(f => f.UI("DateTimeFilter"));
        columns.Bound(c => c.AccountName).Title(Resources.AccountName);
        columns.Bound(c => c.ProjectName).Title(Resources.Project);
        columns.Bound(c => c.TotalHoursWorked.TotalHours)
                    .Title(Resources.HoursWorked)
                    .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(TotalHoursWorked.TotalHours, '00') #:#= kendo.toString(TotalHoursWorked.Minutes, '00') #")                      
                    .Filterable(f => f.UI(GridFilterUIRole.NumericTextBox)); ;
        columns.Bound(c => c.Status)
            .ClientTemplate("# if (Status == 0) { #" +
            "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/Images/exclamation16.png") +
            "' title='Status: Pending for validation' width='25px' />" +
            "# } #" +
            "# if (Status == 1) { #" +
            "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/Images/approve.png") +
            "' title='Status: Consultant approved' width='25px' />" +
            "# } #" +
            "# if (Status == 2) { #" +
            "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Stamp-blue.png") +
            "' title='Status: Approver approved' width='25px' />" +
            "# } #" +
            "# if (Status == 3) { #" +
            "<img src='" + Url.Content("~/Content/Images/Accept.png") +
            "' title='Status: Account approved' width='25px' />" +
            "# } #"
        ).Title(Resources.Status).Width(100).HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "center-text" });
        columns.Bound(c => c.Status).ClientTemplate(
            "#if(Status == 2 || Status == 3){#" +
            "<button class='export-btn btn btn-primary'> <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt'></span> " + Resources.ExportPdf + "</button>" +
            "#}#"
        ).Title(Resources.Actions);
    })
    .Scrollable()
    .Sortable()
    .Filterable(filterable => filterable
    //.Extra(true)
     .Operators(operators => operators
        .ForString(str => str.Clear()
            .Contains(Resources.Contains)
            .StartsWith(Resources.StartsWith)
            .EndsWith(Resources.EndsWith)
            .IsEqualTo(Resources.IsEqualTo)
            .IsNotEqualTo(Resources.IsNotEqualTo)
        )
        .ForDate(d => d.Clear()
                    .IsEqualTo(Resources.IsEqualTo)
                    .IsGreaterThan(Resources.IsGreaterThan)
                    .IsLessThan(Resources.IsLessThan)
                    .IsNotEqualTo(Resources.IsNotEqualTo)
        ))
    )
    .Groupable()
    .Resizable(resize => resize.Columns(true))
    .Excel(excel => excel
        .FileName("Timesheets.xlsx")
    ).Pdf(pdf => pdf
        .FileName("Timesheets.pdf")
    )
    .Events(e => e.ExcelExport("excelExport"))
    .Pageable(pageable => pageable
        .Refresh(true)
        .PageSizes(new List<object> { 10, 20, 50, "All" })
        .ButtonCount(5))
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.Id);
            model.Field(p => p.Id).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.Date).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.AccountName).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.TotalHoursWorked.TotalHours).Editable(false);
            model.Field(p => p.ProjectName).Editable(false);
        })
        .Read(read => read.Action("DownloadTimesheets_Read", "TimeSheet"))
        .PageSize(10)
        .Group(groups =>
        {
            groups.Add<ListSortDirection>("Year", ListSortDirection.Descending);
            groups.Add<ListSortDirection>("Date", ListSortDirection.Descending);
            groups.Add(p => p.AccountName);
        })))
```

Extra: the status property of a timesheet:

```
    public int Status 
    { 
        get 
        {
            if (ApprovedByAccount)
                return 3;
            if (ApprovedByApprover)
                return 2;
            if (ApprovedByConsultant)
                return 1;

            return 0;
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to do all that.  Kendo UI has a built in way to handle customization of dropdown filters:

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/filter-menu-customization